# Add the blog link to the top of the page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, blog

I know I suggested this on UserVoice and it was turned down, but I'd like to suggest it again in this forum in hopes of generating enough user interest to change your mind.  I'd really like the blog link to be at the top of the page with the "about" and "faq" links.  There is so much information contained in the blog about the inner workings of SO et. al. that I think it's a disservice to new users to have it buried at the bottom of the page.  Adding 7 characters (" | blog") to the menu items wouldn't take up much room and would improve the flow of information significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still think this is a really good idea.  The fact that some people will still miss it doesn't detract from the value of increasing its visibility.

Comment: Looks like someone's trying to increase their acceptance rate... ;-)

Comment: Creating an example that I can use later to show how meaningless accepted answers are on meta.

Comment: some background... what motivated this change was the per-site blogs, which needed a lot more publicity and promotion and love -- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/

Answer (score 2):

Most people have shown that they are incapable of clicking and reading the About and FAQ pages, so I would have to say that I doubt that moving the blog link to the top would significantly improve anything.

Comment: It might help some people to know that there is a blog.  You might also find that people are more interested in blogs than they are faqs.